# Eclipse android project not generating jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, buildpath

I have an eclipse android project, call it 'myproject'. I have also been working on an android library project in the same workspace, call it 'myproject-lib'.

I set up a project dependency on myproject-lib correctly, and everything had been working just fine.

Recently, I added a new package to myproject-lib, and created a single file (a simple interface) in it. Since then, myproject-lib will not generate the jar file after a build.

**Problems** indicates the following build path error:
*The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/myname/eclipse/MyProject/myproject-lib/bin/myproject-lib.jar*

The *bin* dir is being generated for myproject-lib after a build, and it contains an empty *res* dir and *Android Manifest.xml*. Also, myproject-lib *is* marked as a library and remember, this has been working for me up to a point.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding multiple times, with automatically build on and off.
I've deleted that new package that I added just before the problem started (I suspect that's just a coincidence anyway, I just don't see how that could have caused it).
I've tried restarting eclipse.
I've tried restarting my machine.

I'm running Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was just a stupid mistake on my part. The library project had an error in it, so that's why it wouldn't build the jar.

Comment: Cool, you solved it! Maybe mark your answer as the accepted answer so others can see what worked to fix this issue! By the way if you think that's a stupid mistake you should see some of the stuff I've written in the past!! :)